# segmentation fault invalid memory 0x0

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, memory, gdb

I have an issue with my pointer to a structure variable. I just started using GDB to debug the issue. The application stops when it hits on the line of code below due to segmentation fault. ptr_var is a pointer to a structure

```
ptr_var->page = 0;
```

I discovered that ptr_var is set to an invalid memory 0x0 after a series of function calls which caused the segmentation fault when assigning the value "0" to struct member "page". The series of function calls does not have a reference to ptr_var. The old address that used to be assigned to ptr_var is still in memory. I can still still print the values of members from the struct ptr_var using the old address. GDB session below shows that I am printing a string member of the struct ptr_var using its address

```
(gdb) x /s *0x7e11c0
0x7e0810:   "Sample String"
```

I couldn't tell when the variable ptr_var gets assigned an invalid address 0x0. I'm a newbie to GDB and an average C programmer. Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You might be writing out of bounds somewhere, or have any other number of undefined behaviors going on, it's impossible to say without any code. You could use a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect such problems.

Comment: What about using watchpoints to detect a change in ptr_var? See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I haven't really tried using valgrind. I'd probably start learning now to fix this issue :(

Comment: Have a point just for attempting some debugging, something that is aparrently beyond the ability of many posters here:(

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is set a **watchpoint**, GDB will then stop execution every time a member of a struct is modified.

With the following example code

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
 } Foo;

int main(void) {
    Foo foo;
    foo.val = 5;
    foo.val = 10;
}
```

Drop a breakpoint at the creation of the struct and execute `watch -l foo.val` Then every time that member is changed you will get a break. The following is my GDB session, with my input

```
(gdb) break test.c:8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x4006f9: file test.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/home/sean/a.out

Breakpoint 3, main () at test.c:9
9               foo.val = 5;
(gdb) watch -l foo.val
Hardware watchpoint 4: -location foo.val
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 4: -location foo.val

Old value = 0
New value = 5
main () at test.c:10
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 4: -location foo.val

Old value = 5
New value = 10
main () at test.c:11
(gdb) cont
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample program. However, my variable ptr_var is out of scope during the series of function calls

Comment: @Marss no worries, it doesn't need to be in scope! When ptr_var is created you can attach the watchpoint . However, it sounds like you are hitting general corruption issues? Valgrind is your best bet for that you just call `valgrind myProgram` and the stdout will be really helpful

Comment: Alright, I'll check on that. I did try valgrind and it printed this
`==13348== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`
`==13348==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0`
`==13348==    at 0x1: ???`
`==13348==    by 0xFFF00025E: ???`
at the end it says
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @Marss so that is just catching the access :(, not the set are you able to post the whole program would be happy to debug it for you!

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't. Also, the source is too big :( I'm not sure of what you mean by just catching the access?

Answer (score 1):

If you can rerun, then break at a point where `ptr_var` is correct you can set a watch point on `ptr_var` like this: `(gdb) watch ptr_var`.  Now when you continue every time `ptr_var` is modified gdb should stop.

Here's an example.  This does contain undefined behaviour, as I'm trying to reproduce a bug, but hopefully it should be good enough to show you what I'm suggesting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int target1;
int target2;

void
bad_func (int **bar)
{
  /* Set contents of bar.  */
  uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t) bar;
  printf ("Should clear %p\n", (void *) ptr);
  ptr += sizeof (int *);
  printf ("Will clear %p\n", (void *) ptr);

  /* Bad! We just corrupted foo (maybe).  */
  *((int **) ptr) = NULL;
}

int
main ()
{
  int *foo = &target1;
  int *bar = &target2;
  printf ("&foo = %p\n", (void *) &foo);
  printf ("&boo = %p\n", (void *) &bar);
  bad_func (&bar);    
  return *foo;
}
```

And here's a gdb session:

```
(gdb) break bad_func 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400542: file watch.c, line 11.
(gdb) r

&foo = 0x7fffffffdb88
&boo = 0x7fffffffdb80

Breakpoint 1, bad_func (bar=0x7fffffffdb80) at watch.c:11
11    uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t) bar;
(gdb) up
#1  0x00000000004005d9 in main () at watch.c:27
27    bad_func (&bar);
(gdb) watch foo
Hardware watchpoint 2: foo
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Should clear 0x7fffffffdb80
Will clear 0x7fffffffdb88
Hardware watchpoint 2: foo

Old value = (int *) 0x60103c <target1>
New value = (int *) 0x0
bad_func (bar=0x7fffffffdb80) at watch.c:18
18  }
(gdb)
```

For some reason the watchpoint appears to trigger on the line after the change was made, even though I compiled this with -O0, which is a bit of a shame.  Still, it's usually close enough to help identify the problem.

Comment: The variable ptr_var is out of scope during the series of function calls

Comment: If it is in scope further up the call stack then this strategy will still work.  Either break when it is in scope, or break at some other point and move back up the stack (using `frame` or `up`) to where it is in scope, then create the watch point.  The important thing is that you place the watchpoint when `ptr_var` contains the correct value.

Comment: I execute `watch ptr_var` when it is in scope and has the correct values. After I execute `continue`, it says "Watchpoint 2 deleted because the program has left the block in which its expression is valid." and then the segmentation fault error

Comment: Where you have the line `ptr_var->page = 0;` you must expect `ptr_var` to be initialised to some valid pointer.  From the question I took you to mean that between the initialisation of `ptr_var` and the line that causes the segfault is only a series of function calls that don't reference @Marss `ptr_var`.  You need to insert the watchpoint after the initialisation of `ptr_var` but before the function calls that cause the corruption.  Maybe you could give more details about the scopes of the variables involved, and the structure of your program in the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of problems I often use the old electric fence library, it can be used to find bug in "software that overruns the boundaries of a malloc() memory allocation". You will find all the instructions and basic usage at this page:
http://elinux.org/Electric_Fence

(At the very end of the page linked above you will find the download link)

Comment: After I set `export LD_PRELOAD=libefence.so.0.0`. I get this message `ERROR: ld.so: object 'libefence.so.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.` when running GDB. btw, I ran make with `CFLAGS= -fPIC -g` `LDFLAGS= -shared` and `MAN_INSTALL_DIR= /usr/local/man/man3`

Comment: Normally I just use the static lib by putting the path-name for libefence.a at the end of the linker's command line: /home/myhome/LIBEFENCE/electric-fence-2.1.16/libefence.a

Comment: Yep, I also tried static library link. My lib path is in /usr/lib/libefence.a still gave me the same message after I set `export LD_PRELOAD=libefence.so.0.0` and run gdb `gdb a.out` `ERROR: ld.so: object 'libefence.so.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

Comment: If you link the the code with the static library you don't have to export the shared one.

Comment: I see. Thanks. libefence.a is an archive, right? Not an executable

Comment: Yes, a static library is a collection (archive) of objects.